# how to mimic tinymce textarea behaviour with rendered html

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, textarea

using tinymce one can see that the editor is a `textarea`

but you can write all html tags inside so in fact - you can see `rendered html result`

this is not possible using a regular textarea

what is the secret?

is it possible to mimic this beaviour - using javascript or whatever - without using tinymce?

Comment: They're using the contenteditable attribute, see image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DTgV.png)

Comment: @NickParsons - I'm totally confused now. Inside tinymce code user must point a textarea as the editor

Comment: The textarea gets "replaced" by the conteneditable body / iframe. When you do [`tinymce.init()`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/api/class_tinymce.Editor.html/#init), the textarea gets set to have a style of `display: none` so it won't appear on the screen, and instead, the contenteditable body / iframe is displayed

Comment: @NickParsons - if so - does tinymce use `document.execCommand` for handling with the content?

Comment: Yes, I believe so, they have some information [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/TinyMCE3x@Command_identifiers/) where they say that they use commands to enable rich-text-editor actions. (Also you don't have to use a textarea, you can use a div, just a textarea might be more suitable for posting data)